# How do i get the value of any one of the <tr> in a table when the table is made with a while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) command?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pic = $row["Bilde"];
        $name = $row["Navn"];
        $info = $row["Informasjon"];
        $link = $row["Link"];
        $book = $row["Book"];

        echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><input type='submit' name='tothis' id='img-submit' value='$name'>
                <input type='text' value='$name' name='place' style='display: none;'>
                <img src='images/$pic'/></td>";
          echo "<td>$info</td>";
          echo "<td><a href='$link'>$name</a><br>/<br>
                    <a href='$book'>Booking.no</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
```

with

`if(isset($_POST["tothis"])) {
 $place = $_POST["place"];`

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM bosted WHERE Navn = $place";
 $result = $connection->query($sql) or die($connection->error);`

I have a task at school where i am supposed to make a website about all the possibilities of sleeping over, like in hotels and cabins and stuff, in the area, and i want to make a page where i can display one of the places, depending on which one i click on from the table above, so i don't have to make one individual page for each place. I've tried using:

But then `$place` just becomes the value of the las `<tr>`in the while loop. What should i do to give `$place`the value of the place i click in the table.

Sorry if unclear, but i find it hard to explain exactly what i mean...

Comment: Its not exactly clear to me how your table relates to the `place`, but isn't `$link` pointing to one record of your table?

Comment: Do you want to click on one of the entries in the table an then show some more info? I am not sure what exactly your question is, but it seems like you do not know either ;)

Comment: @FlorianMoser Yes, that's exactly what i want, like in a booking page. That you have like a table with some information, and then when t\you click it you get redirected to a page with more info about one specific place. I just don't know how to do that when i have used 'while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())' to create the table. Do i need to use some kind of array or something?

Comment: I think you are confusing some concepts. php generates your html, and then sends it to the browser (which displays it). But there is now way for php to know if the user clicks on an entry in the table (as this happens in the browser, client side). To archive the effect you described (show more info on click) you need to command php to generate more data, which is only possible by creating a new request to the server (so navigate to a new page or use javascript to do another request).

Comment: @FlorianMoser Yeah, but the problem is: let's say i have 7 places in my database that i print into a table using a while loop. The variables printed is given the values of the next place in the database after each time the loop runs. So let's say i put this loop in a form, and just put in an input with the value of `$name`, so i can retrieve that information with php to use on another page. The problem then is that because the variables are given new values after each time the loop runs, the variables will always end up with the value of the last place printed...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an empty row with a single cell that spans all columns and put your result there? Then use ajax to populate the cell for you...

PHP File:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pic = $row["Bilde"];
        $name = $row["Navn"];
        $info = $row["Informasjon"];
        $link = $row["Link"];
        $book = $row["Book"];

        echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><input type='submit' name='tothis' id='img-submit' value='$name'>
                <input type='text' value='$name' name='place' style='display: none;'>
                <img src='images/$pic'/></td>";
          echo "<td>$info</td>";
          echo "<td><a href='$link' id='link'>$name</a><br>/<br>
                    <a href='$book'>Booking.no</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }

echo "<tr><td colspan="3" id='details'></td></tr>";
```

JavaScript File (site.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("#link").on("click", function () {
            var src = "urlwithdetail.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: src,
                success: function (place) {
                    $("#details").html(place);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```